# Compare Two JSONArray's with integer values , If Value is same then change that texview color

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have two arraylist in my model class which are containing integer values.Im getting both arrays in my adapter and comparing values .I want this, when any value of first array matches with second array then in list that specific list row item text view should be in red color.Arraylist size can be increase and decrease .

Below I'm providing code .Please review and provide me solution .

```
public ArrayList<GetDoctorScheduleDetail> getDoctorScheduleDetails;// parent model class which is containing both bottom arraylist
    public ArrayList<GetBlockedTimings> getBlockedTimingses = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<AvailableTimeSlots> availableTimeSlotses = new ArrayList<>();

     for (int i=0;i<getDoctorScheduleDetails.size();i++)
        {

            all_time_id = pojo.getAvailableTimeSlots().get(position).getTimeSlotId();
            compare.add(all_time_id);
            for (int j=0;j<getBlockedTimingses.size();j++) {
                all_block_id = pojo.getGetBlockedTimings().get(position).getFkTimeId();
                compare_fk.add(all_block_id);
                if (all_time_id==all_block_id)
                {
                   /* if (all_time_id==all_block_id)
                    {*/
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Hi It's matched"+i +""+j,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("searching...1",+i+" "+j);
                }
                else  if (all_time_id!=all_block_id)  {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"No matched"+i +""+j,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("searching...1",+i+" "+j);
                }
               /* Log.e("found_first_index: ", i + " second_index: " + j);
                Log.e("searching... ",+i+" "+j);*/
            }

        }
```

Second JSONarray values are not coming in model class

```html
public class MyScheduleJSONParser {
    public static final String TAG = "MyScheduleJSONParser";

    static ArrayList<GetDoctorScheduleDetail> doctorScheduleDetailList; // parent model array object
    static List<AvailableTimeSlots> availableTimeSlotses;// child model array to save 1st json array values object
    static List<GetBlockedTimings> getBlockedTimingses;// child model array to save 2nd json array values object

    public static ArrayList<GetDoctorScheduleDetail> parseData(String content, int index) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
            JSONArray details_jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Detail");

            doctorScheduleDetailList = new ArrayList<>();
            availableTimeSlotses = new ArrayList<>();
            getBlockedTimingses = new ArrayList<>();

            JSONObject detailObject = details_jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);
           // for (int i = 0; i <= detailObject.length(); i++) {
                GetDoctorScheduleDetail slot = new GetDoctorScheduleDetail();//parent model class in this I'm storing other parameters rather then 2 jsonarry(AvailableTimeSlots,GetBlockedTimings)
                slot.setDateOfSlot(detailObject.getString("DateOfSlot"));
                slot.setScheduleId(detailObject.getInt("ScheduleId"));
                slot.setBlockId(detailObject.getInt("BlockId"));
                slot.setFkTimeId(detailObject.getInt("fkTimeId"));
                slot.setDeleted(detailObject.getBoolean("IsDeleted"));
                slot.setFkScheduledId(detailObject.getInt("fkScheduledId"));
                slot.setUtcDateOfSlot(detailObject.getString("utcDateOfSlot"));


                /* this is to fetch AvailableTimeSlots data*/
                JSONArray availableTimeSlots = detailObject.getJSONArray("AvailableTimeSlots");

                /* this loop for fetch AvailableTimeSlots data*/
                for (int j = 0; j < availableTimeSlots.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject innerDataObject = availableTimeSlots.getJSONObject(j);

                    AvailableTimeSlots timeSlots = new AvailableTimeSlots();//child model to save available array data
                    timeSlots.setTimeOfSlot(innerDataObject.getString("TimeOfSlot"));
                    timeSlots.setTimeSlotId(innerDataObject.getInt("TimeSlotId"));
                    timeSlots.setTimeofSlotDateTime(innerDataObject.getString("TimeofSlotDateTime"));
                    availableTimeSlotses.add(timeSlots);// adding data in child model list
                    slot.setAvailableTimeSlots(availableTimeSlotses);// adding data in parent model   public void setAvailableTimeSlots(List<AvailableTimeSlots> availableTimeSlots){this.availableTimeSlots = availableTimeSlots;}
                    doctorScheduleDetailList.add(slot);// adding in parent list
                }
                /* this loop to fetch GetBlockedTimings data*/

                if ((detailObject.getJSONArray("GetBlockedTimings")) != null) {
                    JSONArray getBlockedTimings = detailObject.getJSONArray("GetBlockedTimings");
                    /* this loop for fetch GetBlockedTimings data*/
                    for (int k = 0; k < getBlockedTimings.length(); k++) {
                        JSONObject getBlockedTimingsJSONObject = getBlockedTimings.getJSONObject(k);
                        GetBlockedTimings blockedTimings = new GetBlockedTimings();
                        blockedTimings.setFkTimeId(getBlockedTimingsJSONObject.getInt("fkTimeId"));

                        getBlockedTimingses.add(blockedTimings);// adding data in child model list
                        slot.setGetBlockedTimings(getBlockedTimingses);//adding data in parent model public void setGetBlockedTimings(List<GetBlockedTimings> getBlockedTimings){this.getBlockedTimings = getBlockedTimings;}
                        doctorScheduleDetailList.add(slot);// adding in parent list
                    }
                    //doctorScheduleDetailList.add(slot);
                    return doctorScheduleDetailList;
                }
          //  }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doctorScheduleDetailList;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue with your code?

Comment: Hi,@Karan, Please check my MyScheduleJSONParser class and tell me how I can add "GetBlockedTimings" jsonarray values in model.My "AvailableTimeSlots" array I storing values but don't know why second is not working.

Comment: did you try to debug and check if there are values feeded to object you want?

Comment: @Karan,Issue is I want save all timeslot ids in an array and block id's also in an array then, I want to compare timeslot array's first value with all the values of block id .If both are same then show pop up same.

Answer (score 0):

as I understood your problem , change like this

```
  all_time_id = pojo.getAvailableTimeSlots().get(position).getTimeSlotId();
  compare.add(all_time_id);
                 all_block_id = pojo.getGetBlockedTimings().get(position).getFkTimeId();
compare_fk.add(all_block_id);
            for (int j=0;j<compare_fk.size();j++) {
                if(all_time_id = compare_fk.get(j)){
                  ...........
                else{
                  ...........
                 }
```

Comment: @Hi, Lucefer Thanks for reply.I'll apply . I have one more issue that is my 2nd jsonarray values are not adding in model class.

Comment: Hi, @Lucefer, Please check my MyScheduleJSONParser class and tell me how I can add "GetBlockedTimings" jsonarray values in model.My "AvailableTimeSlots" array I storing values but don't know why second is not working.

Comment: log and check data is coming for that  JSONArray getBlockedTimings = detailObject.getJSONArray("GetBlockedTimings");

Comment: Hi@Lucefer, your code save few values , in arraylist .I want save all values in array then match.